# Removing a column of data (string) by using LIKE query, there must be a better way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem with trying to remove a row of data based on a LIKE match in sql. I'm working with SQL Server 2005.

I have a table (@Containers) which holds information like below:-

```
PMBID   DEPT
------  ---------
248057  5,8
249799  5,6,8
249800  5
249941  1,5
249942  1,4,15,16
249943  1,4,5
249945  4
249946  4
249947  4
249966  8,16,23
249967  5,6,8,16
```

Both columns are string, I need a query to be able to remove rows based on departments, for example if the PMBID has department 1,11,23, or 31 in it, it needs to be removed from the table. So with this logic PMBID's...

```
249941
249942
249943
249966
```

would be removed.

So how do I do this (well) in SQL seen as my column is string?

I've been writing queries such as...

```
DELETE FROM @Containers WHERE (Dept LIKE '%1%' OR Dept LIKE '%11%' OR Dept LIKE '%23%' OR Dept LIKE '%31%')
```

Obviously this statement doesn't work as it catches departments like 15, and 16, so for example PMBID

```
249967
```

would be included when it **shouldn't** as it's not explicitly a 1,11,23, or 31 (or a combination of these).

Is this possible with a string column? Can we use the delimiter somehow to improve the query?

I'll stop now as risk of over-complicating the query, please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commas-in-the-list searching problem.  Put commas around `DEPT` and around the values in the string:

```
DELETE FROM @Containers
    WHERE (','+Dept+',' LIKE '%,1,%' OR
           ','+Dept+','  LIKE '%,11,%' OR
           ','+Dept+','  LIKE '%,23,%' OR
           ','+Dept+','  LIKE '%,31,%')
```

Comment: Just had a go and it looks good, will do a little extra testing, but thank you very much. Could you, or someone else explain exactly what this is doing (the +Depts+ part) so I fully understand. Again, Thank you.

Comment: He's adding comma's to the front and back, so that if 4 is the only value in the list, it becomes ,4,  or if 4 is at the front of the list 4, it becomes ,4,,.  That way you can include the comma in the LIKE portion and pick up every result, without having to do multiple LIKE criteria like the answer below.  Much more elegant this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to store data in a comma delimited string, but this will work for department 1 as an example:

```
DELETE FROM @Containers 
WHERE Dept  LIKE '%,1'
   OR Dept   LIKE '1,%'
   OR Dept   LIKE '%,1,%'
```

You have to force commas into the criteria to exclude 1 from catching 11 and so on.

Comment: Ah yeah, other answer is better anyway, much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your time Goat_CO, I went with above.

Answer (score 0):

Might be cleaner to use a function that splits the string into individual values.
Here a good article on the subject:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings